# Edit google play store listing

Tags: android, google-play

I have released an app on google play store with privacy policy link which is no longer available now so, is it possible to add valid privacy policy link without uploading new APK?

Comment: is your privacy policy URL  hard codded in your app ?

Comment: No, I meant privacy policy link in google developer account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not about programming, please refer to Google play customer service.

Comment: Not Possible you must upload a new apk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Change Privacy Policy URL any time from your Developer console

- Log into your Google Play Developer Console
- select All Applications and select the application whose privacy policy you’d like to edit.
- After that, select Store Listing.
- Then, scroll to the section marked Privacy Policy and enter the URL where you have the privacy policy hosted online
- Lastly, be sure to click Save or update.

For more Information You can visit [THIS](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/)

Comment: Button says 'SUBMIT UPDATE' not "SAVE"

Comment: Yes .  whatever it is .. press it

Comment: @NagarajWadakannavar if you find your solution then accept this answer . so that it will helpful to others

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Comment: I'm glad   @NagarajWadakannavar